# Htaccess исключение особых символов

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Помогите пожалуйста написать правильный htaccess, все никак не получается, уже замучился.

Текущая вид ссылок (1): `http://mysite.ru/vb/showthread.php?t=18970`
Требуемый вид (2): `http://mysite.ru/forum/threads/18970`

(1) всегда одинаковые, только цифры на конце разные.

Я написал небольшое правило для htaccess.

```
RewriteRule showthread.php(.*) http://mysite.ru/forum/threads/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Работает, но не до конца корректно. Получаю такую ссылку:
`http://mysite.ru/forum/threads/?t=18970`

`?t=` - лишние символы, подскажите, можно ли это как-то поправить?

Comment: Эти символы нельзя вписать так просто в строку, как вы указываете, он их просто игнорирует

Comment: `RewriteRule ^forum/threads/([0-9]+)$ showthread.php?t=$1 [NC,L]`